# Synchronization service

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm trying to write a local (remote?) service whose only duty is to check, periodically, a remote set of URLs in order to see if some change occured (and, in this case, to update its own DB accordingly).

The reason why `SyncAdapter` isn't a possibile choise is that I can't use a `LoginManger`: I perform the login through a web form, to a third-party website (via SAML, to be precise), keeping the session using a set of cookies. No auth token, no infinite sessions. Thus, no `LoginManager`, and ultimately, no `SyncAdapter`.

On the other side, SyncAdapter handles a lot of things I would really like to do, but I don't know how: it fires the update process with a non-rigid schedule, but based on battery status, network signal strength, and so on. In this way synchronization is almost continuous, and if I got a mail, Gmail app notify it 3, maybe 4, seconds later.

I would like to write my own service, which allow users to have app DB updated (I don't care if it's immediately or twice a day, updates are rare but important, in fact), which doesn't cause battery drains, and also (if possible, not vital), which can be fired/stopped by a foreground activity.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you need help to write a service? Or a confirmation that `SyncAdapter` is not suitable in your case?

Comment: I just need a solution to my problem. Since I already know that scheduling a remote service may cause battery drains and since I can't use Sync Adapter, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the two possibilities. One with doing synchronization by yourself and the other with the "not so well documented" `SyncAdapter`, which are available since Android 2.

There're pros and cons for both:

- A self written Service is well defined and has a tremendous amoutn of examples and documentation.
- Even the Google managers are not really aware of SyncAdapter. I've seen presentations at Google's IO. They talk about the problem of battary draining but do not mention SyncAdapter at all.
- on the other hand, SyncAdapter has all the features (maybe more) then you need. You have to build empty classes, e.g. for Authorization to get it up and running.

I suggest to give SynvAdapter a try. The way I understood the concept and get my first app up and running was with this [SyncAdapter Concept overview](https://sites.google.com/site/andsamples/concept-of-syncadapter-androidcontentabstractthreadedsyncadapter)